# Google Custom Search page map indexing speed

Tags: google-custom-search

We are adding CSE to our large website.

A primary requirement is that time sensitive data, such as an event, must be *removed* from the CSE results soon after the event has passed. Our initial strategy is to use page map data to set a boolean flag on each of these pages for inclusion in the CSE results. While this implementation works well, at more than 14k pages, the cost for Googles Demand Indexing on a  weekly basis is unrealistic. Without the On-Demand indexing, some pages remain un-indexed weeks after their addition to the sitemap.

Are there any other strategies to work around the indexing cost?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I can think of is Linked CSE. It is a CSE where you host the annotations (urls associated with labels, which decide whether url should be displayed or not) lives on your own server.

Because you are not pushing the annotations to Google, you don't incur indexing cost.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/linked_cse